# Does healing work better than offensive spells to minimize losses at the end of combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing

I've been seeing a lot of people (specifically [DNDShorts](https://www.youtube.com/@DnDShorts)) saying that healing is actually not optimal to play. I've always been confused by this, as extending the length of which your party members can fight is always good, and I'm playing in a campaign as a cleric healer.

Is healing actually suboptimal in 5e? Or am I just doing it wrong?

When I say suboptimal, I mean to say if focusing on healing is less effective for helping the party than, say, using offensive magic to end fights quicker. **Does healing works better than offensive spells to minimize losses at the end of combat?**

For a better understanding of my party makeup, we have 2 fighters, a paladin, a sorcerer, a cleric(me), and a rogue. We are all at 1st level.

Second thing I should mention: My character has proficiency in the herbalism kit, which lets me make potions of healing. In a low l;evel campaign, would it be more effective to distribute healing potions that use healing spells?

Comment: I’m not sure we can answer this objectively or even subjectively without delving into opinion. I know I’ve got my opinion, but I don’t think it’s helpful because it’s my experience at my tables, which is different from others.

Comment: For further clarification: Does healing allow for players to shorten combat without significant losses?

Comment: @Playmaker I've edited your actual question to the body of the post. However, it seems obvious to me that healing does not actually shorten the fight, but rather extend it. Do you mean to ask "does using healing allow for players to end combat without fewer losses rather than using offensive spells"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: I do still think that this is much more opinion-focused and nuanced on a per-situation basis than it seems. However, our very own [chat] is a good place to discuss if you'd like.

Comment: The main problem with saying anything conclusive about level 1 tactics/strategy is that level 1 is **randomly lethal**. You can have the best preparation in the world and still have a decent chance of going down after a single hit.

Comment: @biziclop the bigger problem is that you are focussed on level 1, which they will probably be for 1 session.

Comment: Two useful metrics for combat: (1) did you win without anyone perma-dying?  And was that a close call, like did anyone have to roll a death save when they already had 1 or more fail, or have an enemy turn where they could have attacked an unconscious PC but chose not to.  (2) How many total long-rest resources (e.g. spell slots) did you spend during combat, and after combat to get party HP back up ready for another combat. (Short-rest healing via hit-dice can on average heal most of a PC's max HP once / 2 days, except at level 1 where the first HD is maxed.) Prayer of Healing is efficient.

Comment: Besides magic out-of-combat healing like Prayer of Healing (2nd), or per-short-rest stuff like life cleric Channel Divinity for PCs below half HP, there's the Chef feat and bard Song of Rest that can boost short-rest healing via hit dice.  Chef also gives temp HP, or there's Inspiring Leader for a nice buffer going into the next combat.

Comment: Let's also not forget that pen&paper RPGs are not an MMO raid. You don't *have* to be optimal to have fun. That said, Clerics are in concept a very diverse class and a cool choice. You can attack, you can cast spells, you can heal. Other classes are built around just one of those actions.

Comment: @PeterKrebs you don't *have* to be optimal to do MMO raids either, but the ones I know of are structured with the assumption of dedicated in-combat healing

Comment: @Caleth Of course I was just mentioning that because in MMOs the mechanics are explicitly created to give healers something to do in the fight and not having a healer is life&death. In Pen&Paper groups it is not as strict a requirement to have a healer in that way is what I wanted to express.

Comment: @PeterKrebs: Brennan Lee Mulligan made an interesting point in some discussion (perhaps an Adventuring Party or Academy episode), saying that having a healer makes it very unlikely for just one PC to die, unless the enemies really to inflict failed death saves while they're down.  So usually everyone survives, or it's a (near) TPK if everyone gets to low HP totals without anyone actually dying.  But without a healer, there's more room in the middle for someone to die.  (Esp. without a healing potion someone else can administer, or I guess a medicine check to stabilize but not bring them up.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The argument people make is that "damage prevented" is equally good as "damage healed".

If an orc was going to do 25 damage (over the course of a 5-round combat), then you could spend three of the next five rounds casting *cure wounds* to negate the damage -- or you could just kill the orc, which *also* negates the damage, and doesn't cost you three spell slots, and additionally frees up your allies to fight other monsters.

Of course this only works if you *can* kill the orc.  But clerics in 5e are balanced to be pretty good at killing things -- they're *not* a pure-healing class -- so in practice you will find it easier to kill the orc than to heal all the damage it deals.

My approach is to prepare *healing word*, and only use it when someone goes down.  This has several advantages: it doesn't cost an action, it can be used from 30ft away, and the healing is nearly the same as *cure wounds*.

Comment: This works quite well, as I''m considering having my character have a small change in faith(changing subclass) if it works for the DM

Comment: I work on game balance, and my view is that the purpose of healing is to prevent focus damage from bringing down a teammate. Effectively, to make sure incoming damage is roughly equally distributed.  Beyond that, offense is generally better.

Answer (score 12):

My experience is that in-combat healing, of characters above 0hp, using your action; is almost always less effective than using your resources to mitigate incoming damage in other ways. The amount of HP restored vs the expected incoming damage per turn is just too low.

Healing Word bringing a character from 0 to positive with a bonus action is a major exception to "healing spells bad", mostly because it covers two of the caveats in the above statement. You net 1 PC action if they aren't hit before their turn, which at level 1 quite often means an extra enemy down, which will snowball in later turns

Comment: So, aside from Healing Word, healing spells are basically not important at all? Should I not prepare them?

Comment: @Playmaker You certainly shouldn't prepare Cure Wounds *and* Healing Word, at level 1. At higher levels using low level slots to top people up between combats can be OK, depending on how frequent combats are between rests

Comment: @NotArch A level 1 cleric can prepare 3-5 spells, typically 4. Having 2 of those be healing spells is a bad idea for basically any style of game.

Comment: @Caleth Have you played level 1?! It's the deadliest - healing is a priority at that level. An "any style of game" is a bit of an hyperbole. There are definitely games and tables where it's not a bad idea and OP's may be one.

Comment: @NotArch Have you read the spell description for Cure Wounds? It requires an action, has a range of touch, and for all that you get a d8 instead of a d4. Casting Cure Wounds *in combat* is a bad idea at any level, but level 1 is when it's worst. Healing Word is *miles* better

Comment: @NotArch: At level 1, cantrips are still relatively powerful, and you don't have a lot of spell slots.  Healing Word + Sacred Flame or Toll the Dead is on average 2 HP less healing, but the increase in average damage output (zero vs. 4.5 or 6.5 x chance to fail the save) makes up for it because what you really want is to take enemies off the field and prevent their future damage.  OTOH, if you roll well on 1d8 for cure wounds, you might overheal some characters, but it might also let them survive more than 1 more hit before dropping again.  7 HP from a max Healing Word with +3 Wis might, too.

Comment: @NotArch Having more healing spells prepared doesn't mean you're healing any more per turn than you could with just one. You can still only cast one leveled spell a turn whether you prepare one healing spell or four. It will be far more useful to choose spells that allow you to be useful in a wider variety of situations rather than waste all on doing just one thing in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 9):

### Healing is awful in D&D

Healing has one good use, and that is getting someone up from 0hp so they can have a turn or not die. If a character has 1hp they are just as useful as a character with full hp, a character with 7hp getting healed for another 1d8+wis just means the cleric who healed them probably didn't actually do anything useful that turn.

But is damage better? Probably not if you are talking about magic.

The argument for damage is that a dead enemy does 0 damage, but unless your spell is going to kill an enemy then it effectively does nothing to change the flow of any given round of combat.

So what do I do then?

This is where control magic comes into play. If you cast something like hpynotic pattern you can completely take a bunch of enemies out of the combat, they are doing zero damage and it only cost you one spell.

Then you use other control spells to minimise the damage that comes in from whoever is left, and pick off the stragglers.

The primary tactic in D&D is to prevent incoming damage, and that is a combination of control and damage (one without the other is less efficient or entirely useless). How you do that is different in every single combat, but healing remains nigh useless.

Any exceptions?

Maybe. If you use a heal which allows a character to survive an otherwise 0hp inducing hit then maybe it was worth it, but equally if you stunned or killed the enemy so they didn't land the hit at all.

TL/DR:

If you have a sword - hit people, if you have magic - control people.

Comment: This is not my experience at all. I agree that healing is awful, but bringing someone back to consciousness is just one use, and my experience has shown that the other uses are necessary at times. It's important that we remember that our playstyle may not be others, and that answers to questions like this are extra sticky because of that.

Comment: @NotArch do you have any examples of healing being useful that I haven't covered? This isn't an answer based on my experience, it is an answer based on how healing, damage and control actually works in 5e.

Comment: One that's top of mind is that when an ally is hit with a nova strike early enough in combat, healing them to keep them in combat might be the better call than hoping it ends early. But that's just one and there are more. My point is just that this question is hard because of a lack of defined scenario. We can all come up with scenarios that work or don't work - which is why I think this is opinion-based. I thought about writing a similar answer and stopped because it was just going to be a description of my experiences - which may not be useful to OP's undefined situation.

Comment: @NotArch Another case is when a spellcaster with *Counterspell* is put down early in combat and its contribution with *Counterspell* is crucial again the Mad&Evil mage that is using even _control spells_ on the party... This answer is so biased too based on just one experience and playstyle.

Comment: @NotArch: Healing to keep them in combat is exactly what this answer is suggesting: heal them up from 0 before their turn, so they still get to act.  If initiative order doesn't put a healer after an enemy but before them, it's much harder to make that happen.  Keeping them conscious the whole rest of the fight is important for some classes, like barbarians with limited numbers of rages, or other casters with useful concentration spells, but otherwise limping along for the few more rounds of a typical combat might be your best bet, even if it means that character playing more defensive.

Comment: @NotArch: Without spells like Heal (6th), or being a Life cleric, that's not a lot you can do to get someone back up from very low HP that's remotely efficient in terms of actions and spell slots.  If multiple people are hurt, in a bigger party Mass Cure Wounds (5th) is pretty good efficiency, like enough HP for each PC to survive probably one extra hit from enemies you might fact at level 9 or higher.  And if you have spiritual weapon up, you can use it on a turn when you used an action to heal, so it's not a lot worse than Mass Healing Word + cantrip.

Comment: Stuff like Bane or Ray of Enfeeblement (grave cleric) are nice debuffs for multiple or single targets to reduce incoming damage, making existing HP last longer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actaully, this answer suggests the TLDR: "If you have a sword - hit people, if you have magic - control people." Indeed, the 1st part says: until your companions have 1 Hp, there is no use to heal them, because they are useful as they are full HP, don't matter if the next enemy blow will probably knock them out.

Comment: @Eddymage: Yes, that first part of the answer is what I was referring to: heal only if they're at 0 HP, which in 5e is the same thing as "heal to keep them in combat".  (I assume you meant to say 0 HP, not 1 HP, since healing at 1 HP usually won't get them high enough to survive another hit, especially not multiple hits.)  I guess if you care about the RP impact of being knocked unconscious vs. just heavily injured, that might be another justification besides mechanics like concentration or other stuff that drops when unconsciousness.

Comment: @PeterCordes No, I meant really 1HP. This answer builds on the idea that being at 1 HP or at full healt does not matter, since you can do all the actions at your disposal in any case. This seems to be a playstyle where the players rarely face real dangers.

Comment: @Eddymage: Ok, but that's not an accurate summary of what this answer says.  It says "*Healing has one good use, and that is getting someone up from **0hp** so they can have a turn or not die.*"  If you want to stop people from reaching 0 at all, you should heal at HP totals including but not limited to 1 HP.  If you don't want to waste actions and spell slots avoiding that, healing at 1 HP is wasted, unlike healing at 0 HP.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's not my summary: it is exactly the TLDR from the answer.

Comment: I do not think that "a playstyle where the players rarely face real dangers" is an accurate assessment - otherwise the characters would not be at 1hp to begin with.

Comment: @Eddymage: Your earlier comments said *until your companions have 1 Hp, there is no use to heal them*.  But according to this answer, there's still no use to healing them when they're at 1 HP, because as you say, they're still as effective as at full HP.  And earlier you confirmed you meant 1 HP not 0 HP as the time to start healing, again contradicting what this answer says, that healing is only useful to get people up from 0, not when they're at 1.  (Precisely *because* 1 HP is as effective as full, that part you are accurately summarizing, but then suggesting healing at 1.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I never said that. What I mean is that for the answerer healing is only useful when a character is at 0 hp, since until one has >0 HPs (at 1 HPs as well at full health) one's not needing healing. And I strongly disagree with this. I never said that for me the correct moment when starting to heal is at 1 HP.

Comment: @SPavel Yeah, maybe my comment is a little bit biased on other answers and comments by the SeriousBri.

Comment: @Eddymage: You apparently didn't *mean* to say that you should heal at 1 HP, but that's what "*until your companions have 1 Hp ...*" means.  It means don't do anything except when your allies have exactly 1 HP, which would make no sense.  To express what this answer is saying, the appropriate phrasing would be "until your companions have 0 Hp, there is no use to heal them, ...".  That's why I said you probably meant 0 HP not 1 as the time when healing is not wasted if you were trying to summarize this answer.

Comment: For what it is worth I don't advocate getting down to 1hp and yo-yo healing. I advocate playing cleverly and barely getting hurt, but saving your healing for when it is absolutely needed (0hp). I have played characters in all sorts of campaigns and proactive play instead of reactive means I rarely even get hurt. I watch people playing in different styles and cringe as they get hurt when they didn't need to and thank my lucky stars I am not a cleric expected to waste my actions making up for those mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

### It is never* worth it to spend an action on healing

D&D characters are as effective at 1hp as they are at 100hp. If it is worthwhile to cast healing spells (expending spell slots and actions) on someone who still has HP left during combat, then it would be *even better* to spend actions on other things (attacks, cantrips) that bring the combat to an end sooner or mitigate enemy damage, and then spend the spell slots on healing after combat ends, when actions are abundant.

*But there was that asterisk...*

There are a few situations where the above doesn't apply.

#### Sometimes, your teammates are at 0 HP

A character with 0 HP is not dealing damage, but is a single *Healing Word* away from being able to deal damage again. In this situation, healing is a no-brainer. There is almost nothing else you can do with that bonus action (plus spell for the turn) that would be more effective than getting your downed teammate back in the fight.

Technically, this is just a *bonus* action and not a real action, but it means that you can't spend your action for the turn casting other spells (aside from Cantrips), so it could be argued to still be spending an action on healing.

#### Sometimes, your teammates aren't as effective at low HP

I, as a player, choose to play suboptimally when my character is at low HP. Sometimes I have my character panic as they realize that death is one misstep away. Sometimes they get angry to drown out the fear. Sometimes they accept death and make themselves a target to try to go out in a blaze of glory.

Sometimes, characters are selfish and will yell at the cleric for ignoring them when they're in pain (though I haven't played such a character yet).

If your party acts like a *Darkest Dungeon* expedition, then these sorts of roleplay concerns can make it worthwhile to cast healing spells, even during combat, even when it is not necessary mechanically.

#### Sometimes, dropping prone is a big deal

A character who falls to 0 HP falls [prone](https://5e.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#prone) and has to stand up before they can attack without disadvantage (or avoid being attacked with advantage). Spending an action to heal someone before they hit 0hp avoids having them fall prone. Depending on initiative order, failing to do so might the enemy might be able to take advantage of their prone condition to send them right back to making death saves.

*Or worse...*

#### Sometimes, the specter of the instant death rules looms

There is a (somewhat under-discussed) rule in 5e where if an attack reduces you to negative one times your maximum HP, [you die instantly](https://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/damageAndHealing.htm#instantDeath). At low levels (before you have access to *Revivify*) or against monsters which destroy the body on kill (like Gibbering Mouthers), a single lucky enemy crit can take a character from low HP to *gone forever*.

Casting Healing Word on a downed ally creates the perfect conditions for this to happen: they are at extremely low health, can be attacked with advantage, and are still a dangerous combatant from the enemy's perspective. To avoid such situations, it can be useful to keep your teammates with a comfortable buffer in hit points.

#### Finally, house rules may apply

In the popular computer adaptation of 5e, *Baldur's Gate 3*, characters which have just been healed from 0 HP cannot take actions on their next turn. Almost needless to say, if your table plays by that or similar house rules, any strategic or balance wisdom that relies on the rules as written will need to be reconsidered for the new context.

Comment: *but it means that you can't spend your action for the turn casting other spells* - Cantrips are spells in 5e terminology.  You can't cast other *leveled* spells, but can still cast a damage cantrip.  Clerics usually have Toll the Dead or Sacred Flame which are both pretty decent.  But sure, other good options include Mass Cure Wounds (action) + attacking with a spiritual weapon you cast earlier (bonus).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, healing is a way to *maintain the action economy*. Unconscious characters can't take actions, and that means your team loses a large fraction of their capability -- and maybe more, if the character who went down was doing something to reduce the enemy team's action economy (wall spells, fireballs, hypnotic pattern, blocking a door, etc).

If your healing is getting somebody off the floor so they can take a turn they would have missed otherwise, the you've done your job.

If you're healing a hurt character who would be likely to drop the next time they take a hit, then you're doing your job.

If you're healing somebody who still has plenty of hit points, you're not helping and you should probably focus on dealing damage -- or, given you're a cleric, buffing the people who are better at dealing damage than you are.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the only situations you would heal in-combat:

- Save an ally who is reduced to 0 Hit Points and doing death saving throws (Healing Word is your friend)
- Keep a vital member alive and putting out damage / utility (due to their damage output or damage types working really well against the current threat) - The best tool for this particular scenario is likely a Cleric - Life domain and Aura of Vitality (Level 3 spell that grants 1 minute of access to a Bonus Action heal for 2d6 + Wisdom Modifier + 2 from Life domain for an average of 54 Hit Points over 6 turns, ranging between 24 - 84 Hit Points)
- Paladin's Lay on Hands grants a touch range ability (including self) to restore a number of Hit Points up to their "healing pool" (which is 5 times their Paladin levels), renewed after a long rest. So a level 10 Paladin can heal up to 50 Hit Points in one swoop. (Cleric - Life domain gets a similar ability but is vastly more limited in both how high you can top people off and it's a one-time use per long rest, where Paladin can freely choose their numbers)
- AoE healing like Mass Healing Word (3rd level spell) can pick up multiple fallen comrades who dropped to 0 Hit Points within 60 ft. It's only using a verbal component, so you don't even need to stow your weapon to cast. It's only a bonus action so you can still hit enemies with your action.